# How to get signature by JS with contract use ECDSA verify

Tags: solidity, web3js, openzeppelin, ecdsa

I want get **signature** by Javascript

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading their source code it is a ECDSA signature

```
function _verify(bytes32 hash, bytes calldata signature)
public
view
returns (bool)
{
    return ECDSA.recover(hash, signature) == galaxy_signer;
}
```

In order to obtain a valid signature you need to have the private key of `galaxy_signer`.

Comment: yes , thank you sir